# HMCatalog iOS sample app

Tags: ios, siri, accessory, homekit

**Demo code used:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

**Question:**

How can I use SIRI to control the standard services available on HomeKit accessory?

**Steps:**

- I have created a new Home in my HMCatalog app and then
- I have added a **Lightbulb service** accessory in the HomeKit accessory simulator and then
- **paired** it with the HMCatalog app
- and then I have tried to say "hey SIRI, turn the lights on" and it works but it says "Hmmm, only some lights responded. You may want to check on them."

**Questions:**

- how do I get SIRI to control a specific light?
- how do I get SIRI to **control a custom accessory?**

---

This is how my accessory simulator looks like:

[image]

This instead is what my friend SIRI tells me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the light in a room, let's say dining room.  Then you can say "Siri, turn off my dining room light"